# Deleting an element from a list inside a dict in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, deep-copy

```
{  
   'tbl':'test',
   'col':[  
      {  
         'id':1,
         'name':"a"
      },
      {  
         'id':2,
         'name':"b"
      },
      {  
         'id':3,
         'name':"c"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have a dictionary like the one above and I want to remove the element with `id=2` from the list inside it. I wasted half a day wondering why `modify2` is not working with `del` operation. Tried `pop` and it seems to be working but I don't completely understand why `del` doesn't work.

Is there a way to delete using `del` or pop is the ideal way to address this use case?

```
import copy

test_dict = {'tbl': 'test', 'col':[{'id':1, 'name': "a"}, {'id':2, 'name': "b"}, {'id':3, 'name': "c"}]}

def modify1(dict):
    new_dict = copy.deepcopy(dict)
    # new_dict = dict.copy()
    for i in range(len(dict['col'])):
        if dict['col'][i]['id'] == 2:
            new_dict['col'].pop(i)
    return new_dict

def modify2(dict):
    new_dict = copy.deepcopy(dict)
    # new_dict = dict.copy()
    for i in new_dict['col']:
        if i['id']==2:
            del i
    return new_dict

print("Output 1 : " + str(modify1(test_dict)))
print("Output 2 : " + str(modify2(test_dict)))
```

Output:

```
Output 1 : {'tbl': 'test', 'col': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'c'}]}
Output 2 : {'tbl': 'test', 'col': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'b'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'c'}]}
```

I tried looking for answers on similar questions but didn't find the one that clears my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`del i` just tells the interpreter that `i` (an arbitrary local variable/name that happens to reference to a dictionary) should not reference that dictionary any more. It does not change the content of that dictionary whatsoever.

This can be visualized on http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html:

Before `del i`. Note `i` references the second dictionary (noted by the blue line):

[image]

After `del i`. Note how the local variable `i` is removed from the local namespace (the blue box) but the dictionary it referenced to still exists.

[image]

Contrary to `del i` (which modifies the **reference** to the dictionary), `dict.pop(key)` modifies the **dictionary**.

Comment: This visualization is rad! Saves so much time in understanding some of the basics. Thanks for sharing it.

Comment: Personally, I find this answer incomplete, as the question "Is there a way to delete using del?" is uncovered. I would have preferred a reference to https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement

Answer (score 3):

In Python 3, you can do this:

```
test_dict = {**test_dict, 'col': [x for x in test_dict['col'] if x['id'] != 2]}
```

Comment: This is cool. Does `**test_dict` mean all keys except `col` or just the ones prior to `col`?

Comment: @Vinay It actually means **all** the keys. Then whatever keys provided after the comma will be either added (if they didn't exist in `test_dict`) or replaced (if they did exist in `test_dict`)

Comment: @goodvibration I'm pretty sure this only works from Python 3.4 (or 3.6?). Either way, not in **all** versions of python 3

Comment: @DeepSpace: I did remember it would not work on P2, so I explicitly stated P3. I admit I'm not sure about sub version since I'm using P3.6. In any case, it would probably be more efficient to change `test_dict['col']` only (instead of the entire dictionary). There's an answer here below by @Rakesh, which suggests that, and I believe that this method would work in every Python version (2.x and 3.x).

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using a comprehension.

**Ex:**

```
data = {'tbl': 'test', 'col': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'b'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'c'}]}

data['col'] = [i for i in data['col'] if i["id"] != 2]
print(data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'col': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'c'}], 'tbl': 'test'}
```

Comment: came across this method but not sure why I didn't use it :) Btw I guess your intended should be `{'tbl': 'test', 'col': [{'id': 1, 'name': 'a'}, {'id': 3, 'name': 'c'}]}`

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is not working is that you are using del wrong.

If you have a dictionary `d = {'a': [{'id':1}, {'id':2}]}` Then to delete the second element of the dictionary you use `del d['a'][1]` this returns
`d = {'a': [{'id':1}]}`

So for your problem you iterate to find the position of id 2 in the list and then you can simply do `del dict['col'][ix]` where ix is the index of id 2 in the list

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete an element referenced by the iterating variable (the `i`)in the for loop

```
l = [1,2,3]
for i in l:
    if i == 2:
        del i
```

won't work. `l` will still be `[1,2,3]`

what you can do is get the index of that element and delete by using the index

```
l = [1,2,3]
for idx, elem in enumerate(l):
    if elem == 2:
        del l[idx]
```

Comment: You *don't* want to delete elements from a list while iterating over it directly (or over its indexes). At the very least you should iterate in reverse.